# Efficient way to loop through large amount of files, convert them to webp and save the timestamp

Tags: image, file, converters, webp

I have a folder with about 750'000 images. Some images will change over time and new images will also be added every now and then. The folder-structure is about 4-5 levels deep with a maximum of 70'000 images per one single folder.

I now want to write a script that can do the following:

- Loop through all the files
- Check if the file is new (has not yet been converted) or changed since the last conversion
- Convert the file from jpg or png to webp if above rules apply

My current solution is a python script that writes the conversion-times into a sqlite database. It works, but is really slow. I also thought about doing it in PowerShell due to better performance (I assume) but had no efficient way of storing the conversion-times.

What language would you recommend? Is there another way to convert jpg to webp without having to exernally call the command `cwebp` from within my script?

Comment: Is there some purpose to the sqlite database? Surely you can check if the JPEG file modification date is newer than the corresponding WEBP file and if it is newer, or the WEBP doesn't exist, then create it? Also, I would do it in parallel. Also, if I was doing this often I would put the files on an NVMe disk.

Comment: I would think the time consumed by the two first steps is negligible (regardless of it being naive Python, PowerShell or uber-optimized assembly hooking into a state of the journaled file system), compared the last step (JPEG/PNG to WebP conversion). Parallell workers is probably the way to go.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I scrapped the database and started working with multi threading. It got my code running quite more efficient.

Comment: Cool - well done. Good luck.